# Remove the contents of block based on condition

Tags: sed

Below sed removes all occurrences of blocks between {content-start} and {content-end}, but want to remove only block contains the sting 'labtest'.

```
sed -ie '/{content-start.*}/,/{content-end}/d' test.txt
```

test.txt

```
{content-start}
abc1
labtest
def1
ghi1
{content-end}
{content-start}
abc2
def2
labtest
ghi2
{content-end}
{content-start}
abc3
def3
ghi3
{content-end}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{content-start}/{:a;N;/{content-end}/!ba;/labtest/d}' file
```

Gather up the lines between the start and end strings then test the collection for the required string and delete  if positive.